# Style triggers produce no effect

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, datatrigger

I want to implement a "poor's man" toggle button for a menu item. Essentially, when it's checked it should say "Metric" and when it's unchecked - "Imperial". I can't get it to work.

Here's what I tried:

```
<MenuItem IsCheckable="True" IsChecked="True">
    <Style>
       <Style.Triggers>
           <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
              <Setter Property="Header" Value="Metric"/>
           </Trigger>
           <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="False">
              <Setter Property="Header" Value="Imperial"/>
           </Trigger>
       </Style.Triggers>
     </Style>
</MenuItem>
```

It gives me an error

> The member 'IsChecked' is not recognized or is not accssible" (same
>   for Header).

The error goes away when I do `<Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">`, but it doesn't do anything.

I tried directly without the `<Style>`

```
<MenuItem.Triggers>
   <Trigger...>
</MenuItem.Triggers>
```

First, it gave me the same error as above, but when I changed the property to `Property="MenuItem.IsChecked"` it started notifying me that only EventTriggers are allowed.

I subsequently tried with a `DataTrigger` without effect :

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type MenuItem}}, Path=IsChecked}" Value="True">
    <Setter Property="Header" Value="Metric"/>
</DataTrigger>
```

No effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to assign the MenuItem's `Style` property by declaring the `<Style>` as child element of a `<MenuItem.Style>` element.

```
<MenuItem IsCheckable="True" IsChecked="True">
    <MenuItem.Style>
        <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Header" Value="Metric"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Header" Value="Imperial"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </MenuItem.Style>
</MenuItem>
```

Comment: Holy crap... I thought I tried every combination. It worked - thanks. @Clemens, can you explain why without the `<MenuItem.Style>` it was incorrect?

Comment: Because then you don't assign the `Style` property, but just add something to the `Items` collection which is not another MenuItem and hence is ignored.

Comment: @NewDev also in such cases [MenuItem.IsChecked](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.menuitem.ischecked.aspx) when there are only 2 possible Value's, rather than have 2 separate `Trigger`'s, just pick one of your Value as a `Style`'s default setter and only have 1 trigger to switch that value.